# Isekai where an old man is reborn/summoned as a level one god

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga, isekai

It's about an old man, I think he's around 60, that is either is summoned or reborn into that world. I'm thinking the former. He doesn't look like an old man and he was summoned with others that are actually in their teens.

As they were reading out their stats, he misspoke and said he was a level one and that all his states were 9s. So they thought he was useless but really he was a level one god and all of his stats were 999999.

I can't find it no matter how much I search, so if anyone knows it that would be helpful. All of this is pretty much all I remember about it as well, I hope it was enough.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra info you can remember?

Comment: Was this an anime or a manga? It would probably help whoever might be able to identify this (of course, unless you no longer remember).

Comment: Was this manga in colour or in black & white?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150302/old-sci-fi-novel-where-man-uses-horn-to-enter-another-world-learns-he-is-a-god?rq=1  Similar theme

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure this is *[Summoned by Being Involved?! and I Was "God"??](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=174030)*

> I was summoned to an unknown world to defeat the Demon King, but my level seems to be very low when compared to the others that were summoned with me...
>
> Wait a minute, my occupation is "God?"

The main character is a 60-year-old man who's summoned by a king to another world to defeat a demon king. The MC appears in a much younger body, and we never see his original body (at least, not in the first chapter).

Other people were summoned as well (all under the age of 25), and when they're asked to open their status screens to reveal their abilities, it turns out they're all at relatively high levels, like a level 42 hero, a level 40 sage, and a level 52 saint.

When the MC is asked to reveal his occupation, his status screen say he's a god, which, for some reason, the king interprets as him being a servant of god, i.e. a priest. The king then asks what his level is, hoping he's at a high level, but the status screen says he's at level 1. Consequently, he's deemed unworthy to stand on the same platform as the king and the others, and is frogmarched down the steps by a couple of guards, to stand with the crowd below. Even the MC himself seems convinced he's just a level 1 priest and a "lemon".

Later in the story, he opens up his status screen again to look at his individual stats, and they're all at 99999, which he puts down to a glitch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Anony - If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.